# UIImagePickerController not respecting UIImagePickerControllerQualityType on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to build an app that would let user pick and upload a video from the library on iPad. I need the video resolution to 960x540.

I am using the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,nil];
mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

mediaPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540;
mediaPicker.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f;
mediaPicker.delegate = self;


if (self.imagePickerPopOverController.popoverVisible) {
    [self.imagePickerPopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

self.imagePickerPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:mediaPicker];
[self.imagePickerPopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
                                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                          animated:NO];
```

When I use the above code to pick image from camera, the size is 960x540, but when I do the same from gallery, its size is 640x360.

Comment: I haven't checked on the iPhone as such, this app is specifically for the iPad.

Comment: Ah. That would make sense.

Comment: HI, i am having the same problem, did you manage to solve it? Cheers

Comment: Yes, I am now using image quality high for UIImagePickerController and then use the reference URL or media URL to compress using ALExportSession in desired quality.